# rd_kafka_offsets_for_times() returns error -186 (Local: Invalid argument or configuration.)

Tags: librdkafka

I'm trying to get the offset (high watermark offset) for a partition using [rd_kafka_offsets_for_times()](https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/clients/librdkafka/rdkafka_8h.html#ae308aaf534807cfd4c71e423fc214929).

Here is a code snippet:

```
rd_kafka_topic_partition_t* pt0 = rd_kafka_topic_partition_new(topic, 0);
pt0->offset = 0;
pt0->metadata = 0;
pt0->metadata_size = 0;
pt0->opaque = 0;
pt0->err = 0;
pt0->_private = 0;

rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_t* partition_list = rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_new(1);

partition_list->elems = pt0;

rd_kafka_resp_err_t offsets_err = rd_kafka_offsets_for_times(rk, partition_list, 5000);

if (offsets_err != RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR)
{
    printf("ERROR: Failed to get offsets: %d: %s.\n", offsets_err,
        rd_kafka_err2str(offsets_err));
}
else
{
    printf("Successfully got offset.\n");
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to get offsets: -186: Local: Invalid argument or configuration.
```

How do I correct my code to be able to get the offset for the partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use [rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_add](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/clients/librdkafka/rdkafka_8h.html#a123ce30e08b31d4ff0fcf6ebe876173d) to add a topic partition to the topic partition list. For example:

```
rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_t* partition_list = rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_new(1);

rd_kafka_topic_partition_t* pt0 = rd_kafka_topic_partition_list_add(partition_list, topic, 0);
pt0->offset = ~0; // set to max integer value

rd_kafka_resp_err_t offsets_err = rd_kafka_offsets_for_times(rk, partition_list, 10000);
if (offsets_err != RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR)
{
    printf("ERROR: Failed to get offsets: %d: %s.\n", offsets_err, rd_kafka_err2str(offsets_err));
}
else
{
    printf("Successfully got high watermark offset %d.\n", pt0->offset);
}
```